# A correct way to override a built-in mapper in Wicket 6

Tags: java, wicket

Wicket 6 has a default compound request mapper: `SystemMapper`. It contains `BookmarkableMapper`. I need to override it, that is, use my own `FancyBookmarkableMapper` instead.

What I tried:

1. Copy `SystemMapper` class as a whole and change the following line

`add(new BookmarkableMapper());`

to

```
add(new FancyBookmarkableMapper());
```

But this way is very ugly and fragile upgrade-wise (although it seems to work). I mention it here just for the sake of completeness.

2. Using the fact that `SystemMapper` is `ICompoundMapper`, replace the mapper using `add()`, `remove()` and `iterator()` methods:

   ```
   private SystemMapper customizeSystemMapper() {
       final SystemMapper rootRequestMapper = (SystemMapper) getRootRequestMapper();

       IRequestMapper originalBookmarkableMapper = null;
       boolean afterBookmarkable = false;
       List<IRequestMapper> mappersAfterBookmarkable = new ArrayList<>();
       for (IRequestMapper mapper : rootRequestMapper) {
           if (mapper.getClass() == BookmarkableMapper.class) {
               if (originalBookmarkableMapper != null) {
                   throw new IllegalStateException("There are two BookmarkableMapper instances in the initial mappers list");
               }
               originalBookmarkableMapper = mapper;
               afterBookmarkable = true;
           } else {
               if (afterBookmarkable) {
                   mappersAfterBookmarkable.add(mapper);
               }
           }
       }
       if (originalBookmarkableMapper == null) {
           throw new IllegalStateException("There is no BookmarkableMapper in the initial mappers list");
       }

       for (IRequestMapper mapperToRemove : mappersAfterBookmarkable) {
           rootRequestMapper.remove(mapperToRemove);
       }
       rootRequestMapper.remove(originalBookmarkableMapper);
       rootRequestMapper.add(new FancyBookmarkableMapper());
       for (IRequestMapper mapperToAdd : mappersAfterBookmarkable) {
           rootRequestMapper.add(mapperToAdd);
       }
       return rootRequestMapper;
   }
   ```

Not very nice too, although it works as well.

3. Build an implementation of `ICompoundMapper` and decorate `SystemMapper` instance with it. The only way to substitute the built-in mapper is to try to play with `iterator()` method:

   ```
   @Override
   public Iterator<IRequestMapper> iterator() {
       return new Iterator<IRequestMapper>() {
           private Iterator<IRequestMapper> originalIterator = delegate.iterator();

           @Override
           public boolean hasNext() {
               return originalIterator.hasNext();
           }

           @Override
           public IRequestMapper next() {
               IRequestMapper nextMapper = originalIterator.next();
               if (nextMapper != null && nextMapper.getClass() == BookmarkableMapper.class) {
                   nextMapper = bookmarkableMapperReplacement;
               }
               return nextMapper;
           }

           @Override
           public void remove() {
               originalIterator.remove();
           }
       };
   }
   ```

However, this does NOT work, as `SystemMapper#mapRequest()` (actually defined in `CompoundRequestMapper`) uses `mappers` field directly and not via `iterator()` method.

4. The easiest way:

   ```
   private SystemMapper customizeSystemMapper2() {
       final SystemMapper rootRequestMapper = (SystemMapper) getRootRequestMapper();
       rootRequestMapper.add(new FancyBookmarkableMapper());
       return rootRequestMapper;
   }
   ```

Here we add our mapper to the beginning of the list. It extends `BookmarkableMapper` and inherits its `getCompatibilityScore()`, so it has the same score as `BookmarkableMapper` has, and it is earlier in the list, so it takes precedence.

This item 4 actually works. The only thing that makes me ask this question is that actually, both mappers are in the internal list of `SystemMapper` for this approach. Is it guaranteed that my mapper (that was added later and has the same score) will take precedence (including future Wicket versions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest (and official) way is to use `WebApplication#mount(new FancyBookmarkableMapper ()` in YourApplication#init() method.

I'll check tomorrow your concern in 3)! **Update**: improved it with https://git1-us-west.apache.org/repos/asf?p=wicket.git;a=commitdiff;h=0eb63480;hp=5821157738ac43a09232a2aeb0fa2ff808340f4d
Please let us know if you see more improvements! Thank you!

Comment: The page in question is actually mounted using our mapper implementation that extends `MountedMapper`. But when a request from a listener is handled (like a link click), another mapper is used by Wicket (namely, `BookmarkableMapper` from `SystemMapper`). Moreover, `BookmarkableMapper` (which my `FancyBookmarkableMapper` extends) does not have any constructor that accepts mount path. I'm confused.

Comment: Did you try what I suggested ? I'm not talking about pages.

Comment: I added `mount(new FancyBookmarkableMapper())` in my `WebApplication#init()` method before any manipulations with system mapper and before other mounts, and it works. Thanks! I was just a bit confused by using `mount()` for a mapper with no `mountPath` :)